# Concatenating a variable number of arrays in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia

Suppose there is a variable number of 2D arrays which I want to concatenate into a 3D array:

```
n = 10  # Number of arrays, can be changed to other integers
arrays = Dict()
for i in 1:n
    arrays[i] = rand(2,2)
end
```

The syntax for concatenating arrays, as far as I know, is:

`cat(arr1, arr2, arr3, ..., dims=3)`
Since the number of arguments is variable, I can only think of the solution:

```
3d_array = arr1
for i in 2:n
    3d_array = cat(3d_array, arrays[i])
end
```

But how do I concatenate it in the direction `dims=3` with one line only, without for loops, etc.?

Comment: Take a look at `reduce`

Comment: I have tried the following: `reduce(cat, [rand(2,2), rand(2,2), rand(2,2)]; dims=3)`, but doesn't seem to work (and I looked at the documentation and it doesn't say how to deal with keyword arguments)

Comment: `reduce((x,y) -> cat(x,y,dims = 3), [rand(2,2), rand(2,2), rand(2,2)])`

Comment: I've made that an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

given the initial code:

```
n = 10 #random positive integer
arrays = Dict()
for i in 1:n
    arrays[i] = rand(2,2)
end
```

here are some options:

using `cat` with splatting:

```
res1 = cat(values(arrays)...,dims=3) #values(dict) gives an iterable of all values stored
```

using `reduce` with `cat`:

```
res2 = reduce((x,y)->cat(x,y,dims=3),values(arrays)) #using anonymous function to pass kwargs
```

Im gonna guess and assume that you also want that the following equality holds true:

```
arrays[i] == res[:,:,i] # for i in 1:n
```

there is a problem here, as Dicts are unordered, you can check on the display:

```
julia> arrays
Dict{Any,Any} with 10 entries:
  7  => [0.586479 0.280905; 0.805592 0.737151]
  4  => [0.0214868 0.340997; 0.191425 0.271359]
  9  => [0.060134 0.939555; 0.0896634 0.455099]
  10 => [0.990368 0.214775; 0.224519 0.767086]
  2  => [0.578315 0.109518; 0.794717 0.0584819]
  3  => [0.106458 0.287653; 0.523525 0.277063]
  5  => [0.372227 0.151974; 0.921043 0.238088]
  8  => [0.690332 0.14813; 0.771126 0.320432]
  ⋮  => ⋮
```

How to solve this? changing the iterator:

`cat` with ordered splatting:

```
res3 = cat((arrays[i] for i in 1:n)...,dims=3) #using iterator syntax to return ordered values
```

`reduce` with ordered `cat`:

```
res4 = reduce((x,y)->cat(x,y,dims=3),(arrays[i] for i in 1:n))
```

at last, not asked, but my favorite, using broadcasting syntax to put those values on an prealocated array:

```
res5 = zeros(eltype(arrays[1]),2,2,n) #if you know the size beforehand
res5 = zeros(eltype(arrays[1]),size(arrays[1])...,n) #if you dont know
for i in 1:n
  res5[:,:,i] .= arrays[i]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You use `reduce`. The syntax is

```
reduce((x,y) -> cat(x,y,dims = 3), arrays)
```